How i can give context to extends include(Python, Django)
everyone
I have view with context {'title': _('Log in')}
And I render template
login.html
{% extends 'base_auth.html'%}
{% load static i18n %}


{% block title %}
    {{title}}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}`
{% endblock %}

base_auth.html
{% load static i18n %}

{% include 'includes/main.html' %}

    <head>
        {% include 'includes/title-meta.html'}%}
        <!-- Css -->
        <!-- Main Css -->
        {% include 'includes/head-css.html' %}
    </head>
        <!-- Body -->
        {% include 'includes/body.html' %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        <!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
        {% include 'includes/script-file.html' %}
        <script src="{% static 'jarvis/js/app.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>

includes/title-meta.html
% load static i18n %}
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>
    {% block title %}

    {% endblock %}
    -
    'Simple ODB servise'
</title>
<meta  name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
<meta  content="Tailwind Multipurpose Admin & Dashboard Template"  name="description"/>
<meta content="" name="Mannatthemes" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<!-- App favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'jarvis/images/favicon.ico' %}" />

When i render that i have in html
 - 'Simple ODB servise' 
I want have next html
 Log in - 'Simple ODB servise' 
When i render that i have in html
 - 'Simple ODB servise' 
I want have next html
 Log in - 'Simple ODB servise' 
